# How to set the Duplicate parameter name in Angular http request

Tags: javascript, angular

here i have data like below

```
personsData = ["550,360,zarthon"];
```

i want to send this data to the http params and i want to set it as duplicate names  like

```
params = Params.append('person', '550');
params = Params.append('person', '360');.. so on i may have n number of data
```

while sending request i want to send it like

```
www.someurl.com?person=550&person=360 like this
```

i am trying to set it in the below code but i unable to set it

```
let params = new HttpParams();

for (let key in personsData) {
    params = params.set("person",key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using HttpClient:

```
export class exampleService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 example() {
   const params = { person: ['550', '360', '...'] };
   return this.http.get('www.someurl.com', { params });
 }
}
```

You are welcome!

Comment: this i already implemented this will send the values in array but i want to duplicate the param

Comment: it will result in: www.someurl.com?person=550&person=360
What angular version are you using?

Comment: angular 9 i am using

Comment: @Dexter We have the same after an Angular upgrade. The parameter keys are suddenly not duplicated in the url. Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only difference is setting the first time you could simply set first element differently, and then append the rest as suggested in the documentation.

```
let params = new HttpParams();

params = params.set("person", personData.shift());

for (let key in personsData) {
  params = params.append("person",key);
}
```

If by any chance there is a possibility that params will have that parameter beforehand or it will somehow be removed in the middle you could check it on every run of the loop instead.

```
let params = new HttpParams();

for (let key in personsData) {
  params = params.has("person") ? params.append("person",key) : params.set("person",key);
}
```

Comment: will it be like www.someurl.com?person=550&person=360 like this